# calculation of differences between values in T0 and T1 with dyplr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a big dataset and I would like to obtain the difference values of diversity between time T1-T0, I am adding an example dataset:

```
var <- data.frame(Time = c("T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1"),
                           index = c("chao1", "chao1", "shannon", "shannon", "evenness", "evenness" ),
                  values = c(150, 136, 5.6, 4.5, 1.3, 0.5, 120, 113.5, 5.2, 4.1, 1.3, 0.5))
```

I would need to obtain for each index' values one value which is difference as T1-T0, to see the change of diversity between times. Could it be possible with `dplyr`using `mutate`?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This pivots your data into a wider format and then subtracts the difference of T1-T0. The `id` variable is simply to allow the data to pivot, as there are multiple entries that are the same. I remove it in the final function so its not redundant information.

```
var %>% 
  group_by(Time) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Time",
              values_from = "values") %>% 
  mutate(Time_Diff = (T1-T0)) %>% 
  select(index,T1,T0,Time_Diff)
```

The output should look something like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  index       T1    T0 Time_Diff
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 chao1    136   150      -14   
2 shannon    4.5   5.6     -1.1 
3 evenness   0.5   1.3     -0.8 
4 chao1    114.  120       -6.5 
5 shannon    4.1   5.2     -1.10
6 evenness   0.5   1.3     -0.8
```

#### Edit

Based off your comments below the answer, you could also aggregate your scores by the mean or whatever way you want like so:

```
var %>% 
  group_by(Time,index) %>% 
  summarise(mean.val = mean(values)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Time",
              values_from = mean.val) %>% 
  mutate(time.diff = T1-T0) %>% 
  select(index,T1,T0,time.diff)
```

Which will give you this:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  index        T1     T0 time.diff
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 chao1    120.   143       -23.5 
2 evenness   4.65   1.7       2.95
3 shannon    2.25   5.05     -2.8
```

Comment: Great thanks! however I actually realize my dataset is more like this ```var <- data.frame(Time = c("T0", "T0", "T1", "T1", "T0", "T0", "T1", "T1", "T0", "T0", "T1", "T1"),
                           index = c("chao1", "chao1", "chao1", "chao1","shannon", "shannon","shannon", "shannon", "evenness", "evenness", "evenness", "evenness"  ),
                  values = c(150, 136, 115,124,5.6, 4.5, 1.3, 3.2,2.9, 0.5, 5.2, 4.1))```, how do handle replications? Thanks!

Comment: Why are there multiple values for each index? You could possibly aggregate them in some way but I'm not sure if thats what you want or not.

Comment: because I have replications per each time, I will try to aggregate in case, Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I need to keep the replications separates so when I do 
``` pivot_wider(names_from = "Time",
              values_from = values)
``` 
when I dont have T0 I get ``ǸA`` and with T1 as well therefore it will not calculate the difference

Comment: Did the edited part of my answer do the same thing? I didn't change the portion you mentioned.

Comment: no, but  I know why, in my data I have it like this: 
```var <- data.frame(Sample =c("DS22","DC23","DS22","DC23", "DS22","DC23","DS22","DC23","DS22","DC23","DS22","DC23"),
  Time = c("T0", "T0", "T1", "T1", "T0", "T0", "T1", "T1", "T0", "T0", "T1", "T1"),  index = c("chao1", "chao1", "chao1", "chao1","shannon", "shannon","shannon", "shannon", "evenness", "evenness", "evenness", "evenness"  ),                   
                  values = c(150, 136, 115,124,5.6, 4.5, 1.3, 3.2,2.9, 0.5, 5.2, 4.1))```
is it a problem?

Comment: Try the second part first. If it doesn't work, lemme know. I tried with this last comment's data and it worked as well.

Comment: Yes it works, but my idea would be not to get the mean but to keep the values separated, it is ok thanks anyway!

Comment: If thats the case, the first part achieves that. Using the example you give in the comments, the first code gives a time difference for both time points per person as well as their multiple entries.